# VBA ADO Excel Driver SQL Except/Minus operator

Tags: sql, vba, excel, odbc

I have 2 tables (new data and old data) and want to query all new rows that are not present in the old data.

```
SELECT * FROM new 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM prev
```

I wanted to do this with the 'EXCEPT/MINUS' operator in VBA ADO(using Excel sheets as tables), however it seems that EXCEPT is not an accepted operator?

I get a run-time error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error in FROM clause.
```

Is it just a feature that is not available in the ADO ODBC Excel Driver?
Other queries work just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ADO doesn't support the full SQL server SQL syntax, so `EXCEPT` may not be available to you.

Comment: @TimWilliams ... OP is not using SQL Server but running SQL on Excel sheets, hence using the JET/ACE SQL syntax which does not support `EXCEPT`.

Comment: That's what I meant - they are trying to use SQL server (T-sql) syntax which is not supported via ADO [against Excel files as datasource]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables and then select only those rows in *NewTable* that have no corresponding entries in *OldTable*. To do this you will need to work out which fields correspond to each other in the two tables.

```sql
SELECT * FROM NewTable 
LEFT JOIN OldTable ON NewTable.Field1 = OldTable.Field1
WHERE OldTable.Field1 IS NULL
```